InDesign Data Merge multiple records: prevent results outside of page margins
I am trying to create PDFs for printing on pre-cut name labels (in this case 14-up on an A4 page - with 15mm margins top and bottom, 5mm margins left and right, and a 2mm gutter).

However InDesign sees fit to create an extra set of records per page, which not only extend outside of the declared page margins, but outside of the page boundary (at bottom in the screen grab shown, but also to the right when running a similar experiment):

Any idea how to prevent this?

Notes:

I have not used Preview Layout at any time with this file (having already rebuilt the file from scratch after encountering problems which are apparently pretty common).
I have tried experimenting with a much bigger bottom margin, but the same number of records per page are still produced.
For this particular job I have resorted to manually rearranging the results for this print run, but will need to create further runs in the near future.


It's not an answer to your question, but I would do this differently. Set up a document where the text frames are linked. Make 3 paragraph styles. Set the style with the first name to always start in a new frame. Put your data into a temporary table and quickly style the columns with the 3 styles. Turn the table into text. Paste it into the story. If set up correctly new pages will automatically be added.

There's no way to resolve this by just looking at your description, this is a see what works kind of problem, but maybe try to add a 1-2mm spacing between the rows (or try different values), so you can force Data Merge to add some vertical space between the labels, which could prevent this from happening.
